# Cisco-like command Line Interface

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, cisco

I'm looking for a way to implement a fairly basic Cisco like command line interface on my Ubuntu server appliance (12.04 in particular).

I've come across the following project: [CLISH](http://clish.sourceforge.net/) however, documentation is sketch and it seems to be quite stale.

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing and might you know of any similar projects / approaches?

Comment: You mean like the `ip` and `route` commands that are already similar to IOS?

Comment: not quite ... more like the 'netsh' (netsh.exe) program on windows

Comment: Are you trying to implement actual functions or just the shell ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not long after posting this question, I came across the [Klish project](https://code.google.com/archive/p/klish) It is an improved version of Clish with better support and more features.

There is a slight learning curve but it is very well thought out.

The goal was to turn a standard linux box into an appliance that can be managed from the CLI like a Cisco router or switch.  Klish (along with some bash and ruby scripts) is highly configurable via XML and has made it possible to configure network interfaces, VLans, and services such as DHCP, iptables, etc. from a single unified shell.

Comment: Check "vtysh" it is used in Quagga project:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtysh/

Answer (score 2):

[Quagga](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/) (ex-Zebra) does not only emulate Cisco shell, but properly sets up routing table and handles a set of routing protocols ranging from RIP till BGP.